# Temperature converter doesn't return correct value

Tags: cobol, jcl

```
         IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                               
         PROGRAM-ID. TEMP1 .                                    
         ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                  
         DATA DIVISION.                                         
         WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                               
         01  WS-A PIC 9(2).                                     
         01  WS-B PIC 9(2).                                     
         PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                    
             ACCEPT WS-A.                                       
             COMPUTE WS-B ROUNDED = ( ( 9 / 5 ) * WS-A ) + 32.  
             DISPLAY WS-B.                                      
             STOP RUN.
```

This is my program for accepting temperature in Celcius and converting it to Fahrenheit. I have created a `LOADLIB` and a `COPYLIB`. Also one `JCL` for compilation and `RUNJCL`. No error is coming, but when I give any input (e.g. 98) in `RUNJCL`, it always shows 32 as output. What is the problem?

Comment: It seems your question was in COBOL, I fixed it for you. (http://caseconverter.com/ to the rescue!).

Comment: When pasting, just highlight the code you want to copy, then paste. The line-numbers make it more difficult for anyone to try your code. Watch your tagging. Stick to COBOL and Mainframe and JCL where the JCL is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result you are getting is always 32, then WS-A is zero, because something multiplied by zero and adding 32 will always be 32.

I suspect that you have in your JCL something like this:

```
//SYSIN DD *
00212
```

When you do the ACCEPT, you will only get 00 from that.

When using ACCEPT for little testing programs it is a good idea to DISPLAY what you get, so you can see.

Either make WS-A larger, or the value on the card following your SYSIN smaller.

It if also possible you have other problems causing the value of WS-A to be treated as zero. So, can you paste the JCL from file 2 on the spool for your JOB. With the line-numbers it generated :-)

And the SYSIN card data (your 98). Look out particularly for any "SYSIN generated" statements in your JCL output.

Here's your program. I've got rid of unnecessary things, and changed the names of WS-A and WS-B. Now that WS-B has a proper name, you can see as you create it that it is the wrong length, it needs to be at least three digits.

```
   ID DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. TEMP1. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  INPUT-CENTIGRADE                    PIC 9(2). 
   01  OUTPUT-FARENHEIT                    PIC 9(3). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       ACCEPT                       INPUT-CENTIGRADE 
       DISPLAY 
               "CELSIUS COMING IN " 
               ">" 
                                    INPUT-CENTIGRADE 
               "<" 

       COMPUTE OUTPUT-FARENHEIT ROUNDED 
                                    = ( ( 9 / 5 ) 
                                        * INPUT-CENTIGRADE )
                                      + 32 

       DISPLAY 
               "FARENHEIT GOING OUT " 
               ">" 
                                    OUTPUT-FARENHEIT 
               "<" 
       GOBACK 
       .
```

The output from running the program is:

```
CELSIUS COMING IN >98<   
FARENHEIT GOING OUT >208<
```

Running this version of your program with "0098" for input gives this:

```
CELSIUS COMING IN >00<   
FARENHEIT GOING OUT >032<
```

Comment: I suspect you are correct.  This could be error-proofed by accepting a full line, triming spaces from the line, and using function num-val() on the remaining to convert to INPUT-CENTIGRADE.

Comment: @JoeZitzelberger good thought. I'll expand later on why the value gets chopped (not all COBOLs do it that way) and do a couple of examples for more secure ways to get data from `ACCEPT`. Thanks.